# Access VBA - event updates all records instead of just current record

Tags: sql, vba, database-design, ms-access-2016

I have a main form (formAB) with combobox (comboboxAB) with two option FormA and FormB (referencing subfrmA and subfrmB). After the user selects an option from comboboxAB I want the field to lock on the current form.

As of right now, after the user selects an option from comboboxAB the field locks on every record not just the current one. So when I want to create a new record I can’t edit the comboboxAB field.

Code:

```
    If Me.comboboxAB.Value = “FormA” or Me.comboboxAB.Value =“FormB” 
       Me.comboboxAB.Locked = True
    Else 
       Me.comboboxAB.Locked = False
    End If
```

I tried the code on the Form_Load event and the AfterUpdate event.

While my code looks like it’s using smart quotes it is not.

Comment: @June7 do you have any recommendations? Thanks!